# python requests

Tags: python, requests

Как заполнить данные на сайте `https://seo-akademiya.com/poiskovik-2/?utm_source=airseoweb&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=after`, чтобы пришло смс на телефон?

Пытался отправлять данные по ссылке с `data` таким вот кодом, на смс не приходят, возможно я делаю, что-то не так:

```
import requests

data = {
    "hiddenautocomplete": '',
    "name": "effefe",
    "email": "*******",
    "cc": "380",
    "phone": "*******",
    "cc_full": "*******",
    "package": "Business-1651",
    "ism": '1',
    "utm_source": "airseoweb",
    "utm_medium": "link",
    "utm_campaign": "after",
    "utm_content": "15jul",
    "utm_term": "p1649",
    "idname": "poiskovik2",
    "idname": "poiskovik2"
}

html_code = requests.post('https://seo-akademiya.com/poiskovik-2/?utm_source=airseoweb&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=after', data=data)
print(html_code.text)
```

Comment: Если через браузер вы это можете сделать, то смотрите в инструментах разработчика запрос, который браузер посылает. И смотрите разницу вашего запроса и того, что посылает браузер.  Запустите локально en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat (nc -k -l 10000) и выполните запросы к нему (т.е. замените хост и порт в запросах на localhost:10000), чтобы увидеть полностью http запросы в двух случаях. Это самый простой и быстрый способ увидеть в чем разница.

Comment: Я не понял ничего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе нужно отправлять POST сюда: https://seo-akademiya.com/assets/php/seolead.php

Comment: огромное спасибо!